# Google chrome 29.0 is not working with webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to load google chrome browser with watir-webdriver, but while invoking any URL in the browser it is throwing following error

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: Unknown command 'WaitForAllTabsToStopL
oading'. Options: AcceptOrDismissAppModalDialog, ActionOnSSLBlockingPage, Activa
teTab, AddBookmark, AddDomEventObserver, AppendTab, ApplyAccelerator, BringBrows
erToFront, ClearEventQueue, CloseBrowserWindow, CloseTab, CreateNewAutomationPro
vider, DeleteCookie, DeleteCookieInBrowserContext, DoesAutomationObjectExist, Dr
agAndDropFilePaths, ExecuteJavascript, ExecuteJavascriptInRenderView, GetActiveT
abIndex, GetAppModalDialogMessage, GetBookmarkBarStatus, GetBookmarksAsJSON, Get
BrowserInfo, GetBrowserWindowCount, GetChromeDriverAutomationVersion, GetCookies
, GetCookiesInBrowserContext, GetDownloadDirectory, GetExtensionsInfo, GetIndice
sFromTab, GetLocalStatePrefsInfo, GetMultiProfileInfo, GetNextEvent, GetPrefsInf
o, GetProcessInfo, GetSecurityState, GetTabCount, GetTabIds, GetTabInfo, GetView
s, GoBack, GoForward, InstallExtension, IsDownloadShelfVisible, IsFindInPageVisi
ble, IsMenuCommandEnabled, IsPageActionVisible, IsTabIdValid, MaximizeView, Navi
gateToURL, OpenFindInPage, OpenNewBrowserWindow, OpenNewBrowserWindowWithNewProf
ile, OpenProfileWindow, OverrideGeoposition, RefreshPolicies, Reload, RemoveBook
mark, RemoveEventObserver, ReparentBookmark, RunCommand, SendWebkitKeyEvent, Set
BookmarkTitle, SetBookmarkURL, SetCookie, SetCookieInBrowserContext, SetDownload
ShelfVisible, SetExtensionStateById, SetLocalStatePrefs, SetPrefs, SetViewBounds
, SimulateAsanMemoryBug, TriggerBrowserActionById, TriggerPageActionById, Uninst
allExtensionById, UpdateExtensionsNow, WaitForBookmarkModelToLoad, WaitUntilNavi
gationCompletes, WebkitMouseButtonDown, WebkitMouseButtonUp, WebkitMouseClick, W
ebkitMouseDoubleClick, WebkitMouseDrag, WebkitMouseMove, AcceptCurrentFullscreen
OrMouseLockRequest, AddOrEditSearchEngine, AddSavedPassword, CloseNotification,
DenyCurrentFullscreenOrMouseLockRequest, DisablePlugin, EnablePlugin, FindInPage
, GetAllNotifications, GetDownloadsInfo, GetFPS, GetHistoryInfo, GetInitialLoadT
imes, GetNTPInfo, GetNavigationInfo, GetOmniboxInfo, GetPluginsInfo, GetSavedPas
swords, GetSearchEngineInfo, GetV8HeapStats, ImportSettings, IsFullscreenBubbleD
isplayed, IsFullscreenBubbleDisplayingButtons, IsFullscreenForBrowser, IsFullscr
eenForTab, IsFullscreenPermissionRequested, IsMouseLockPermissionRequested, IsMo
useLocked, KillRendererProcess, LaunchApp, LoadSearchEngineInfo, OmniboxAcceptIn
put, OmniboxMovePopupSelection, PerformActionOnDownload, PerformActionOnInfobar,
 PerformActionOnSearchEngine, RemoveNTPMostVisitedThumbnail, RemoveSavedPassword
, RestoreAllNTPMostVisitedThumbnails, SaveTabContents, SetAppLaunchType, SetOmni
boxText, SetWindowDimensions, WaitForAllDownloadsToComplete, WaitForNotification
Count,
```

It might be throwing this error because of Chrome update where as webdriver is not supporting the updated API's,
I also tried to update watir-webdriver gem, but it is saying nothing to update (its up to date)  My watir-webdriver version is `watir-webdriver-0.6.4`

Kindly let me know if any one else is facing the same issue or any one found out the solution for the same.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of chromedriver? https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

Comment: Yes, I am using latest version of chromedriver in windows i.e. chromedriver_win32_2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gaurav, I've had the same issue.

Here are the steps how i fixed this:

```
1. Remove old the versions (ruby, watir, devkit)
2. Install to Ruby 2.0.0-p195
3. Install devkit
4. Add latest chromedriver to your $PATH
5. gem install watir-webdriver 
6. gem update --system
7. gem update
8. gem cleanup
```

Also update the chromedriver executable to the latest version (and double check it in your path).
I have: ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14) [i386-mingw32] && watir-webdriver(0.6.4)

Voila:

```
C:\Ruby200\bin>irb
irb(main):001:0> require "watir-webdriver"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.2) on port 9515
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x3cac37de url="data:text/html;charset=utf-8," title="data:t
ext/html;charset=utf-8,">
irb(main):003:0> b.goto "stackoverflow.com"
=> "http://stackoverflow.com/"
irb(main):004:0> b.inspect
=> "#<Watir::Browser:0x50eee9c0 url=\"http://stackoverflow.com/\" title=\"Stack
Overflow\">"
```

Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: Hey Sveatoslav... When I tested same issue in different machine, it works fine, but not working in another machine, even if I installed Ruby 2.0 and updated drivers... Kindly suggest what needs to be done here... Thanks in advance

Comment: Just follow the steps, from above .. and also check your $PATH

Comment: I followed same steps, and the path is also correct, but still chrome is not working. anyways thanks for the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue. I am getting this error exactly when I am trying to navigate to driver.goto("google.com").

But if I revert my Chrome version from 29 to 27 then its working fine. So I think the issue is from chrome version 29 or chrome driver version chromedriver_win32_2.2.zip

So please downgrade the chrome temporarily....

Comment: Yes that is fine, even i tested with Chrome 27 and its working fine, but I want to know why its not working with Chrome 29.0 and what is the solution for this.

Comment: Hi Sharma,  there is already a open ticket here for the same issue https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=277073 and Link to Download Chrome old versions --> http://www.oldapps.com/google_chrome.php?old_chrome=12288?download

Comment: I experience the same issue as well. I resolved it by upgrading to the  most recent chromedriver: http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

Comment: I also upgraded chromedriver, but no luck for me :( , I hope you are using Windows and chromedriver version is chromedriver_win32_2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of chromedriver. Also make sure that the old old on NOT in your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade to the latest version of selenium-webdriver?

```
gem install selenium-webdriver
```

Remember that watir-webdriver is just a wrapper around selenium-webdriver. It is actually selenium-webdriver that does the interaction with chromedriver. Typically, when there is an update to chromedriver, there also needs to be an update to selenium-webdriver.

There were 2 updates to selenium-webdriver since the latest chromedriver update. It is possible that one of the updates addressed your issue.

Comment: Yes I did that and running updated version, but no luck with that. It will work with ruby 2.0, the problem is with ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

Use the Latest jar file of selenium web driver- selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar

and chromedriver_win32_2.3.zip for chrome driver.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue and we fixed it by moving to ChromeDriver 2.3 in both Mac and Windows
Versions I use:
Ruby version: 1.9.3-p194
Watir-webdriver version: 0.6.4
Selenium-webdriver version: 2.33.0

if you can make sure chrome driver is in the PATH, this should work. No need to upgrade to ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You would use capabilities to point to the right binary file of the browser to be launced.But not all versions of chrome browser is supported by different versions of chromedriver. You will find exceptions stating that version of browser expected is greater or equal to 30.0.

For ex:- Chromium Browser(33.0.1729.0 )works fine with ChromeDriver 2.7 and not the with the older ones.

You can choose from all the chromedriver version available from the link below:- http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

So try to use the browser version supported by the chromedriver.