# Getting Access is denied. (5) (ChildProcess::Error) in rubymine

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver, rubymine

Getting below the error when I try to create an object of web browser in my code:

```
$browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie

**ChildProcess::Error: Access is denied. (5)**
```

Got no idea what is causing this and how to resolve it. Previously it used to work fine on the same system. I just re-installed ruby and everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this there would be a few steps, try to see if it's working outside of rubymine. Also what is the ruby version are you using ?

First of all check that your [IEDriver executable](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/cpp/prebuilt/x64/Release/?r=82d4873e262a449c0db751f36da654708e7bc1ec) is in the path.. Open cmd and run:

```
C:\>IEDriverServer
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.31.0.0
Listening on port 5555
```

Also try following these [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459244/google-chrome-29-0-is-not-working-with-webdriver/18499640#18499640).
Works like a charm for me:

```
C:\>irb
irb(main):001:0> require "watir-webdriver"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> $browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
=> #<Watir::Browser:0xdef8a40 url="http://localhost:5555/" title="WebDriver">
irb(main):003:0>
```

My Ruby version details:

```
C:\>ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]
```

Installed gems:

```
C:\>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.0)
childprocess (0.4.1.rc3)
ffi (1.9.3 x86-mingw32)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
minitest (4.3.2)
multi_json (1.8.4)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
rubygems-update (2.2.2)
rubyzip (1.1.0)
selenium-webdriver (2.40.0.rc1)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
watir-webdriver (0.6.7)
websocket (1.0.7)
```

Comment: Problem is only with rubymine, i executed same piece of code from command prompt and it worked well.

Comment: And my ruby version is ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]

Comment: This means it's not a watir-webdriver/cucumber/ruby question. Your env. seems to be Ok. Keep digging into rubymine side.

Comment: I did gem cleanup and it uninstalled childprocess gem. After that i am able to launch IE with rubymine.

Comment: Yeah, looks like there is a know issue related to childprocess gem https://github.com/jarib/childprocess/issues/71

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by switching from Chrome to FireFox within my local RubyMine configurations (TARGET_BROWSER=firefox in the Environmental Variables section of RubyMine).

None of the other solutions worked.